# Control Template not recognized in XAML using VS

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm new to VS and XAML and I was following a tutorial on using control templates to
customize buttons.

```
<Window x:Class="Kromelodeon.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kromelodeon"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="399,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Ellipse Fill="Orange"></Ellipse>
            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Grid>
```

For some reason, I'm getting an error that "Template" is not recognizable
or accessible on line 10

Can anyone point out why? I was originally trying to make four-sided diamond-shaped buttons using the 
Path controls ie M 0,0 100,100  etc but got so many error codes I decided to start over with something simpler. This is a WPF desktop app.

Please help.

Comment: XAML is XML. Replace `<Button .../>` by `<Button>...</Button>`.

Comment: In case Clemens comment isn't totally clear. The template must be inside the Button tags. You close Button and then the Button.Template tag is outside the button rather than inside.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ControlTemplate` needs to be inside the begin and end tags of the button like below.

Also, your `ControlTemplate` needs to have a root element. In this case I used a Grid which is very common.

Elements that sit on a line by themselves and have no children (nested elements) can be closed off with `/>`

```
<Button Content="Button" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="399,70,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="75">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Fill="Orange" />
                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help! This all makes sense!

Comment: I tried <Button> Content ="Button"  .. followed by the rest of the code and closed the button at the end with </Button> which didn't work at first but now I see from Keithernet's example to contain the other parameters ie alignment and so on within <Button > and then nest the control template and close with </Button> then it worked. Thank you again!